# reading seconds from mysql and convert to hours

Tags: php, mysql, database

So im basically a complete beginner in php/mysql this is the current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, userid, date, rig, hash, miner_hashes, temp, fanrpm, rack_loc,ip, uptime, gpus, driver, cpu_temp, miner, miner_version, mem, powertune, fanpercent, voltage, miner_secs, version FROM hash WHERE rig='bbf3ec' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" 
. $row["version"]. "</td><td>" 
. $row["driver"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["gpus"] . "/8</td><td>" 
. $row["miner"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["miner_version"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["miner_secs"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["rig"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["rack_loc"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["ip"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["cpu_temp"] . "c</td><td>"
. $row["hash"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["miner_hashes"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["temp"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["voltage"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["fanpercent"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["powertune"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["mem"]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
```

Currently I'm just printing miner_secs value as INT from database, but I want it to convert to hours first and then to insert it into a row, any idea on how to do that?
Just once again I'am a complete beginner in this stuff, every explanation is highly appericated!

Comment: Convert seconds to hour is as simple as dividing them into 360 and you only need to do some adjustments to show minutes and seconds. But, what do you mean exactly when you say "then to insert it into a row"? Please edit your question to expand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do calculations on the minor_secs even if it is a string.

```
. round(($row['miner_secs']/60)/60,2) . "</td><td>"
```

I'm dividing the output by 60 and then 60 again. Then rounding it to avoid insane precision.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, quite simple in the end, I tried to do something like that but my syntax was bad. Thank you very much!